# Install org module on XEmacs

Tags: org-mode, xemacs

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I installed XEmacs 21.4 (patch 22) I want to use org module BUT fail to install/configure it.

In my case I don't use `.emacs` but rather I have `~/.xemacs/custom.el` where I keep all my settings. `org` module did not exist originally hence I did this:

```
git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
```

This created org-mode directory. Then I added these 2 lines to `custom.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/susja/org-mode/lisp") 
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/susja/org-mode/contrib/lisp" t)
```

It did not load `org` module. Then I ran `M-x list-packages` and did NOT see `org` package. Could someone please help me to configure `org` module in order to handle `.org` files?

Comment: As far as I know, XEmacs is effectively dead; the version you installed is 7+ years old.  I suggest you install [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html) instead, which is actively developed.  My best guess is that `org` relies on newer features that the old XEmacs version you have does not supply.

Comment: Also XEmacs compatibility code has been removed from the master (dev) branch of org. So org 9.0+ will not support XEmacs.

Answer (score 2):

Well my solution was simple :_
Based on comments I realized that org module is not supported in XEmacs hence I uninstalled XEmacs and installed GNU Emacs. After that I did not have any issues.
Thanks for help.